# errno 13 in Python while saving a file in a directory

Tags: python, urllib, permission-denied

I am trying to download a file from the internet and saving it in a directory but I get an error "Permission denied", which is clear what is it.

Is there any way to give my application(I am developing a Qt4-desktop application) and using urllib for download and saving the file, it looks like this

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,saveLocation,eventHandler)
```

I have tried to start application and my IDE as an admin in windows, but still  I am getting this error

Comment: does the program have permision to save in the folder it is in?

Comment: well this is my first windows application and this was the question, how  would I give him such a privilige?

Comment: try `urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename="file.txt")`

Comment: yeah this works, but still, the files are saved in the directory of the project and not a specific one

Answer (score 1):

By using `urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename="file.txt")` you are able to save it to the folder the program is in. If you want to access other folder you have to be sure to have the right privilages to other folders.

In windows right click and go to properties of the folder you want to save in and change the folders permisions so that the user that the program is on will have read & write enabled in that folder.

Comment: As I said, a ran it as an Admin and it didn't help, I gave my accound a full control on that folder and  it didn't work, I think it would be enough to save the files in the projects directory

Comment: The program has to have the same user as the folder that you want to save in.